# Samsung phones bootloader unlock

Tags: samsung, bootloader, rom, sim-unlocking

I have a samsung tablet gt-n8000 and I want to flash a custom rom . Should I first unlock the bootloader?  if yes , how to do that ? fastboot commands does not work anyway on my tablet so I can not use fastboot oem unlock.

Comment: From my experience Samsung devices usually don't work this way and they are not flashed via fastboot but via odin. Unlocking and user data erase happens after flashing the ROM on first boot. Search for a tutorial exactly for your device and ignore ever other tutorial!

Comment: Thanks Robert . But I found nothing about bootloader unlock for my device . There are  some tutorials about flashing custom roms for my device but nothing about bootloader unlock

Comment: As I said usually you just flash the ROM and on next boot you are getting the option to unlock the device.

Answer (score 0):

Under developer option, Enable OEM unlock.

First find custom rom as per your mobile model. Connect mobile to computer having developer kit. Root the mobile and flash rom.

Comment: My android version is 4.1.2 and it has no OEM Unlock option . meanwhile , fastboot commands does not work . It does not recognize my device .

Comment: Install proper usb driver as per mobile. Enable usb debugging.